# Grant Access to Azure DevOps A. Data Factory Repo

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

Our organization has changed name and with it our emails (xxx@abc --> xxx@def), and apparently we can no longer connecter Azure Data Factory to Git.
We get the following error:

> You have GIT enabled in your data factory. Publishing in 'Data Factory' mode is disabled. Please switch back to GIT mode to make further changes.
> Read about our Best Practices.

Also the switch from ADF to Devops Git is greyed (see screenshot below)

How do we fix this ?

PS:  I have access to Azure Devops and to all the repositories in it, that is why I do not get it why we have this problem

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Have you tried unlinking the GIT and relinking it?

Comment: Since you mention of the org change, can you check ARM template deployment logs if any for errors?  also verify if you or your RG has necessary permission  built-in Data Factory contributor role or `Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/write permission` and make sure all your data sets - linked services details are correct functional and connecting without errors.

Comment: @ray the disconnect button is grey. It says the following : "git configuration settings must be modified in your collaboration branch"

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT everything else seems to be okey, I can even login Azure Devops and check all repositories including the one connected to ADF

Comment: On your Azure DevOps tenant, your account is added using email or AAD account. Any  stale configuration or  creds maybe confusing ADF  connecting to Azure DevOps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible scenario can be, you had the previous Azure DevOps tenant with `xxx@abc` credential and now when you moved to `xxx@def`, you have an Azure AD account to connect to ADF. Or the other way around. In the backend this is causing mismatch when ADF and Azure DevOps tenant are passing credentials for connecting. Try to clear browser data or cache and explicitly login into DevOps account using same creds from ADF before testing.

See similar in MS DOC: [Connect to Git repository failed due to different tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/ci-cd-github-troubleshoot-guide#connect-to-git-repository-failed-due-to-different-tenant)